# UK visa type to attend conference and training in London

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, conferences

I'd like to visit London for a week to attend a conference (2-3 days) and a short 3-day non-recreational training course.

**(1) What is the correct type of visa (and subtype) for activities listed above?** Training may or may not be the main reason for the visit.

according to VISITORS APPENDIX 3. PERMITTED ACTIVITIES FOR ALL VISITORS (EXCEPT TRANSIT VISITORS)
https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

As a visitor i am permitted to undertake any activities in paragraphs 3 – 27. Can i undertake any of them or just a subset that corresponds to selected visa type/subtype?
If i select Visit -> Tourism -> 6 month in visa application form and tell about conference and course then

1. Can i undertake activities listed in 5 (a) attend meetings,
   conferences, seminars, interviews; under "Business – general
   activities" subsection?
2. Can i undertake a short non-recreational course that does not include english language training from 25-b-(ii)? What is an accredited institution?
3. Is there a more appropriate visa type for the visit with a plan that includes activities from paragraph 5(a) and 25-b-(ii)?
4. Can i undertake any activities from paragraphs 4-27? (not 3 A visitor may visit friends and family and / or come to the UK for a holiday)
5. Is "Study - Study (non point-based system) - short-term student 6 month?" a better choice for activities listed in the beginning of this message 5(a) and 25-b-(ii)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based upon what you wrote, you should select from the drop-downs so that the result looks like this...

[image]

This will put you on the logic path to apply for a "Standard Visitor Visa", and can do all of the things listed in Appendix 3.

After the rule change in April 2015, UKVI does not differentiate permitted activities for for visitors.

Comment: So "Visit -> Tourism -> 6 month" is what they call the standard visitor visa and will allow me to do anything from Appendix 3, not just a particular subsection? Is it ok that i'm going to spend almost half of my visit on the training course? Thank you!

Comment: @akisap, yes it's really ok. Really and truly. At this point you are over-thinking it.  I suggest you worry about something else :)

Comment: Any word on when that web site will be updated to reflect the now year-old changes?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, reminded by my answer, I fired off an email last night. It's not clear at all why the site has fallen into delinquency.  Let's keep each other posted on it...